# NatTable - Quick Search in the Excel like filters

Tags: java, eclipse, filter, nattable

I have a NatTable grid and use excel like filters in order to filter my content. However, I want to add a feature to the filters as a quick search (not unlike the excel one)

[image]

Can anyone give me advice on how I might do that?

I've noticed that the other nattable filter FilterRowHeaderComposite has a textbox filter for filtering words that contain the typed string, so I wonder if I could somehow combine it with the ComboBoxFilterRowHeaderComposite to get a combobox with a quick-search feature.

Can I have two header layers, one with comboboxes and the other with the textbox?

Or maybe combine them in one cell as to work like the regular filter and only when I press on the filter icon to expand into the comboboxes context menu?

Or are there already implementations for this feature I'm trying to do, in NatTable 1.2.0 or 1.3.0? (I'm currently using 1.1.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NatTable questions typically get more attention in the Eclipse forum as you already noticed.

For others having the same question, I answered the question there: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1070518&goto=1709109&#msg_1709109